# Error while running script in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter-plugins

```
    com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Kernel32
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.os.ProcessUtils.killWinProcess(ProcessUtils.java:133)
    at org.openqa.selenium.os.ProcessUtils.killProcess(ProcessUtils.java:81)
    at org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess$SeleniumWatchDog.destroyHarder(UnixProcess.java:247)
    at org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess$SeleniumWatchDog.access$200(UnixProcess.java:201)
    at org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess.destroy(UnixProcess.java:125)
    at org.openqa.selenium.os.CommandLine.destroy(CommandLine.java:153)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary.quit(FirefoxBinary.java:259)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.quit(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:204)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver$LazyCommandExecutor.quit(FirefoxDriver.java:377)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.stopClient(FirefoxDriver.java:323)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:119)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:221)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:216)
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.FirefoxDriverConfig.createBrowser(FirefoxDriverConfig.java:95)
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.FirefoxDriverConfig.createBrowser(FirefoxDriverConfig.java:21)
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.WebDriverConfig.getPreparedBrowser(WebDriverConfig.java:233)
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.WebDriverConfig.threadStarted(WebDriverConfig.java:220)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread$ThreadListenerTraverser.addNode(JMeterThread.java:610)
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverseInto(HashTree.java:998)
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverse(HashTree.java:980)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.threadStarted(JMeterThread.java:579)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.initRun(JMeterThread.java:567)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:257)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 35 more
```

I'm getting the error above when run Jmeter script.
I am able to launch the browser but my URL fails to hit and the error above appears.

Comment: Please tell spcefic detail

Answer (score 0):

You are missing class found in `jna-X.X.X-platform.jar`, you should add it to your Class path, if you use maven add dependency as:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.java.dev.jna/platform -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
    <artifactId>platform</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Or download [jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.java.dev.jna/platform/3.4.0) and put it in Jmeter's lib folder